# Bind to a generic number key in tmux?

Tags: tmux

In tmux, is it possible to set a key binding with a number key in a way that it works will all number keys, without repeating the binding for every individual number key (i.e. `bind C-b <number>` instead of `bind C-b 0`, `bind C-b 1` etc.)?

Comment: why do you want to have this "feature"?

Comment: So that I don't have to map every single number key individually.

Comment: you didn't answer my question. why do you want to make `c-b + 0-9` 10 short-cut combinations trigger the same function?

Comment: To switch to panes by their index (i.e. remap the default `C-b q <number>`).

Answer (score 0):

Tmux options are just tmux commands.

You should be able to create a bash script that sets the Tmux options you want.

You could then have that script run automatically when Tmux starts up (do this in .tmux.conf)